# How to return a multiline string as 4 fields in a select query

Tags: sql-server, select, sql-server-2008-r2

a `nvarchar(100)` field contains info on more lines, since every line has a different information (somehow every line number has a meaning: first line is name, second is last name, ...) I would like to query that field and to have four fields as result. I'd like to use a single select statement to do this (even in background it uses a funcion or a view).

I tried to use `charindex` and `replace` but i was not able to end up with a single query.

Somehow the query

```
select MULTILINEFIELD from TABLE
```

returns:

```
'John
Doe
34
Male'
```

I would like to turn it into

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, AGE, GENDER FROM SOMETHING
```

The "newline" in my case is `char(10) + char(13)`, i already got rid of new lines with this:
select

```
  REPLACE( REPLACE(MULTILINEFIELD , char(10), '')  , char(13), '@')
  from TABLE
```

that gives

```
John@Doe@34@Male
```

I used '@' as a char that for sure i won't find in the database.

I hope i expressed myself.

Comment: After this you can use split function to split with delimeter "@".Thats it.

Comment: do you mean splitting by myself or using a specific `split` function?

Comment: Most split functions return a table with one row per value; OP wants one column per value.   user, please post the charindex query you tried and any errors or incorrect values you got from it.   You can get the results you want with the proper use of CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data doesn't have any periods in them you could do this easily with PARSENAME.

```
declare @MultiLineField varchar(50) = 'John
Doe
34
Male';

with normalizedValues as
(
    select REPLACE( REPLACE(@MultiLineField , char(10), '')  , char(13), '.') as FullData
)

select 
    PARSENAME(FullData, 4) as FirstName
    , PARSENAME(FullData, 3) as LastName
    , PARSENAME(FullData, 2) as Age
    , PARSENAME(FullData, 1) as Sex
from normalizedValues
```